# spring and vaadin integration

Tags: java, spring, servlets, vaadin

I'm trying to implement an application with several `ui`s - vaadin, jsp and etc.

It was working with simple `jsp` but then I decided to use vaadin as ui.

I've created vaadin servlet(and spring servlet left too).
My `web.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/pmc-web-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>another-pmc-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>UI</param-name>
            <param-value>com.xxxx.app.pmc.vaadin.PmcUi</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>pmc-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>another-pmc-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>pmc-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/JSP/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jsp/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I've created vaadin `table` component and adjusted it for my needs. I used autowiring for service.

```
package com.xxxx.app.pmc.vaadin.components;

import com.xxxx.app.pmc.model.Project;
import com.xxxx.app.pmc.service.project.ProjectService;
import com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer;
import com.vaadin.ui.Table;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component("projectTable")
public class ProjectTable extends Table {

    private static final String CAPTION = "Projects";
    private static final String[] headers = { "Project name", "Project owner", "ID" };

    @Autowired
    private ProjectService projectService;

    public Table createTable() {
        this.setContainerDataSource(projectDatasource());
        this.setVisibleColumns(headers);
        this.setSelectable(true);
        this.setImmediate(true);

        return this;
    }

    public IndexedContainer projectDatasource() {
        IndexedContainer indexedContainer = new IndexedContainer();

        for(String header: headers) {
            indexedContainer.addContainerProperty(header, String.class, "");
        }

        List<Project> projects = projectService.findAllProjects();

        for(int i = 0; i < projects.size(); i++) {
            Object id = indexedContainer.addItem();
            Project item = projects.get(i);
            indexedContainer.getContainerProperty(id, headers[0]).setValue(item.getProjectName());
            indexedContainer.getContainerProperty(id, headers[1]).setValue(item.getProjectOwner());
            indexedContainer.getContainerProperty(id, headers[1]).setValue(item.getProjectId());
        }

        return indexedContainer;
    }

}
```

`ProjectService` is a spring bean too.

```
@Service("projectService")
public class ProjectService {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    public void insertProject(Project project) {
        projectRepository.store(project);
    }

    public List<Project> findAllProjects() {
        return projectRepository.getAllItems();
    }

    public Project getProject(String id) {
        return projectRepository.get(id);
    }

}
```

`ProjectRepository` is another spring bean. It uses `SqlSessionTemplate` bean from MyBatis.

```
@Repository("projectRepository")
public class ProjectRepository implements IRepository<Project> {

    private static final String STORE_PROJECT = "Project.insertProject";
    private static final String GET_PROJECT_BY_ID = "Project.getProjectById";
    private static final String GET_PROJECT_LIST = "Project.getProjectList";

    @Autowired
    private SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate;

    @Override
    public void store(Project object) {
        sqlSessionTemplate.insert(STORE_PROJECT, object);
    }

    @Override
    public Project get(String id) {
        return sqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(GET_PROJECT_BY_ID, id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Project> getAllItems() {
        return sqlSessionTemplate.selectList(GET_PROJECT_LIST);
    }

}
```

When I wrote an application using spring `controller`(using JSP) - it was working fine. 
But when I added vaadin - `JSP` stopped working and vaadin application throws `NullPointerException` for `ProjectService`, `ProjectRepository`... all the beans I use.

**What is the problem?**
All my context `xml` context files are simple.

```
<import resource="classpath:com/xxxx/app/pmc/pmc-service-context.xml"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.app.pmc"/>
```

And my `pmc-web-context.xml` has this lines too.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:annotation-config/>
```

It was working fine with JSP so I think the problem is not with spring declarations itself but with integration of spring into vaadin of mine.

**How to resolve it?** 
When I for example created `ProjectTable` object manually - it throws `NullPointerException` for `ProjectService`. When I create `ProjectService` manually - it throws `NullPointerException` for `ProjectRepository` and so on. It seems autowiring simply doesn't work.

P.S forgot to add my UI code

```
package com.xxxx.app.pmc.vaadin;

import com.xxxx.app.pmc.vaadin.components.ProjectTable;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Title;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Title("PMC")
@Component("pmcVaadin")
public class PmcUi extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        VerticalLayout mainLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        ProjectTable projectTable = new ProjectTable();
        mainLayout.addComponent(projectTable.createTable());
        mainLayout.setSizeFull();
        setContent(mainLayout);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you suspected your Spring beans are created, but in application and Spring's servlet contexts. Your Vaadin servlet has no access to any of those.

For detailed (manual) solution with code either check [Vaadin's wiki](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Spring%20Integration) or search for a proper [Vaadin's add ons](https://vaadin.com/directory#browse:vaadin,search=spring) that will do the job for you (personally I recommend SpringVaadinIntegration).

The typical idea is to programmatically pass Vaadin servlet to one of Spring's utility classes (eg.: WebApplicationContextUtils) and retrieve application context (loaded by ContextLoaderListener). If you need servlet context, then from code examples I have seen, you do the same as above, but additionally manually read context (eg.: using XmlWebApplicationContext) and set application context as it's parent.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy option is to use Configurable support. It'll do some aspect magic and all java objects annotated by `@Configurable` will be automatically integrated into Spring. You can find more details in [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable). Also please note that to represent context information in GUI you will have to use session beans. That causes the problem with session size, and in bigger applications makes it impossible to cluster.